# How to render edited Image with node compositor (no scene)?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I want to render an image that I edit with node compositor but it render only grey image. Long story short, I want to use compositor like a classic image editor. Is it possible? If yes, how can I render my edited image?[image: compostitor as image editor?]

Answer (score 1):

you can just drag and drop the image in the compositor and then use your nodes setup and render it with F12:

[image]

Comment: maybe you need to connect the alphas too....for your case.

Comment: Thanks for help. As you can see on my screenshot, this is exactly what I'm doing but I've got a grey render. Do you know why?

Comment: nope, but if you provide your blend file, i will take a look. Please use file->external data ->. pack resource before

Comment: I figured it out! The original image is bigger (a lot) than my output resolution so it rendered a tiny grey part of my image 
Tthank you for you time!

Comment: no problem, you  are welcome